# Ubuntu 18 Virtual Box Mac shutting down on navigation

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, shutdown, mac, navigation

I set up Ubuntu as a disk image on virtual box on my mac (latest OS), and it loads fine, and I can do stuff (open firefox, cmd, etc) but if I navigate away from the VM it shuts down with state "aborted". What can I do to prevent this?